prawn/prawnto/prawnto_2 - external image not opening even with require 'open-uri'
I inherited an out of date rails site that I've been updating. One of the changes I need to make is to load some external images in a PDF using prawn instead of a local file. I've added the require 'open-uri' but I'm still receiving the error: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen
My code looks like this:
class ExamplePdf < Prawn::Document
  require 'open-uri'

  def initialize(foo)
    super()
    @foo = foo
    letter
  end

  def letter
    # some text and other formatting

    image open(@foo.image.url), scale: 0.5
    # also tried:
    #image open foo.image.url, scale: 0.5

    # some other text and formatting
  end
end

Called in a controller:
pdf = CombinePDF.new
letter = ExamplePdf.new(@foo).render
pdf << CombinePDF.parse(letter)

I've looked through other threads and the documentation, but I find that this particular part of prawn is not very well described or documented. It's shown in an example here, but not further explained at all.

ruby 3.3.0 and rails 7.1.0

In that case you will need to use URI.open? The URI library used to manipulate Kernel#open, to support calling open with a URI or local file system file; however this functionality was deprecated in 2.7 and removed in 3.0.

D'oh! That was it. Changed it over to URI.open and it works perfect. Thanks for the sanity check. Submit an answer so I can mark it correct
